# Exported Excel File Always Read-Only

Tags: php, excel, export, export-to-excel, readonly

I have the following codes below for exporting database data into .xls file but when I open and tried to save the file a prompt from MS Office Excel show with following text "We can't save `TechGirl.xls` because the file is read-only. To keep your changes, you'll need to save workbook with a new name or in a different location".

Even thought I can easily save the file to new filename or location. I'm also eager to find solution on how can save the file automatically. or to make the file not a read only. What is the following codes i missed or following solution with this?

```
<?php  
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password');  
    mysqli_select_db($conn, 'databasename');  

    $setSql = "SELECT * FROM techgirl";  
    $setRec = mysqli_query($conn, $setSql);  


    $columnHeader = "First Name" . "\t" . "Middle Name" . "\t" . "Last Name";  

    $setData = '';  

    while ($rec = mysqli_fetch_row($setRec)) {  
        $rowData = '';  
        foreach ($rec as $value) {  
            $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";  
            $rowData .= $value;  
        }  
        $setData .= trim($rowData) . "\n";  
    }  


    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");  
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=TechGirl.xls");  
    header("Pragma: no-cache");  
    header("Expires: 0");  

    echo ucwords($columnHeader) . "\n" . $setData . "\n";  
?>
```

Comment: Hi, maybe it is depending on which OS and browser you are using. For me on Win7 + Firefox53 the file was saved without read-only flag, and Office could edit it easily. So, what kind of software are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 OS, MS Office 2013 and Mozilla Firefox 51.0.10.588 (32-bit)  @Geza Boehm

Comment: Okay I think I agree with you @Geza Boehm . I try using Opera 44.0.2510.1159 (PGO) and open the file directly after it downloaded and add some text and  save then the MS Office Excel 2013 promt like this **"Some features in your workbook might be lost if you save it as Text(Tab delimited). Do you want to keep using this format?"**. What happening to this stuff??? is the downloaded excel file in the database depends on the browser we are using? Office version? or Operating system we have?? What is the best thing I need to do about this?

Comment: This is a protection built into the most recent versions of MS Excel, OpenOffice, etc to prevent malware being injected into a local PC through spreadsheet files downloaded from the internet

Comment: Although you should also get complaints from MS Excel, etc telling you that the file format doesn't match the file extension, because you're pretending that a csv file is an Excel file

Comment: So the basic answer is the read-only flag depends on OS and/or browser.
Second question is the content of the file. Since you save TAB separated data into TechGirl.xls, the Office recognize it as plain text data file. It shows you as a normal spreadsheet, but in the background the file is not real XLS, but a TAB delimited text file. So saving is problematic, that's why the warning message.
I suggest using CSV file format, if you would like to keep it simple. Or use a real excel exporter for PHP, for example PHPExcel library.

Comment: Okay I got it but I think we need more conversation about this I recommend to create a discussion about this. i have a lot of question about this. And in addition what is the best solution I need to do now? or please give me a copy of a code of a solution with this. @Geza Boehm

Comment: I suggest you to try the CSV format, it is quite similar to this TAB separated text what you are already using. Maybe the Office can digest it easier.
On the other hand, if you need fancy cell formating, you should go for the PHPExcel, but i have no experience with that.

Comment: Okay thanks for recommendation @Geza Boehm. Did you have some codes of it can i have one?